# Prevent YouTube from knowing what videos I watch

Tags: youtube

I'd like to find a way to prevent YouTube from knowing what videos I like so it won't tell me what videos I may like (recommendations, suggestions etc.).

Is it possible to do anything in my browser for that? I use **Firefox**.

Could you please explain to me how they know about the videos I watch?

I don't have a Google account, so do they use JavaScript or Cookies to know about the videos I watch? 
Or maybe they associate my IP to the videos from server-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a combination of all three of JavaScript, cookies, and your current IP address.

The simplest thing is to use Firefox in "[Private Browsing](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-use-firefox-without-history)" mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>). Of course, to get YouTube to "forget" you you'll need to create another browser session after each video you watch.

A more robust method is to use some sort of proxy that rotates your IP address, but that's beyond the ken of this site.